# Python LonamiWebs/Telethon get group name of received message

Tags: python, telethon

Code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChat, PeerChannel

api_id = 123
api_hash = '123'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if(event.chat.title == 'BotTest'):
        print(event.raw_text)
        

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Problem:
So this code works if group(BotTest) has me/bot(one user) "`event.chat.title`"(`event.chat`) exist but if i join second user (group now has 2 peoples) new messages result in [`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'`] so there no [`chat`].

How can i get chat from this object?

UPD: There is [`event.chat_id`] how question is how to get name from ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/updates.html#entities):

```py
async def handler(event):
    # Good
    chat = await event.get_chat()

    # BAD. Don't do this
    chat = event.chat
```

So, you should change how you get your `chat` object to:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    if(chat.title == 'BotTest'):
        print(event.raw_text)
```